# Find unique values for the variables to make all statements true

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, logic-grid

In this puzzle you have to find unique values for the variables to make all statements true. I have proceeded to here and now I seem to be stuck.
[image: Logic equation puzzle]

Comment: F = C+H but C, H are at least 2 and 3, so F >= 5.  H > B and B >= 2 so H > 2

Comment: H > B so B < 9.  3I >= B so I < 3.  i = 2.  So C, H are at least 3 and 4, F >= 7 and C, H <= 6.

Comment: Where is this from? We have a policy of crediting the original creators of all puzzles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Final answer:**

> A = 7
>  B = 4
>  C = 3
>  D = 9
>  E = 6
>  F = 8
>  G = 1
>  H = 5
>  I = 2

Below are all the steps that I took to find this answer:

**Step 1**

> `CG = C`, ⟹ G has to be 1.
>  `6C = CE`, ⟹ E has to be 6.
>  [image: step1]

**Step 2**

> `3I ≤ 9`, ⟹ I is 2 or 3.
>  `H > B`, and B ≥ 2, ⟹ H ≥ 3. And of course B < 9.
>  `F = C + H`, and with C ≥ 2 and H ≥ 3 makes F ≥ 5. And F can't be bigger than 9, ⟹ C ≤ 6 and H ≤ 7.
>  [image: step2]

**Step 3**

> `H > B`, ⟹ B ≤ 6. I has to be 2 or 3:
>  - If I = 2, ⟹ B ≥ 3 ⟹ H ≥ 4.
>  - If I = 3, ⟹ H ≥ 4. In both cases: H ≥ 4.
>  [image: step3]

**Step 4**

> **Let's rule out H = 7.**
>  Suppose H = 7. then C = 2 and F = 9 (`F = C + H`). Then I = 3.
>  Then: A + F + H + 1 = C + DI ⟹
>  (≥4) + 9 + 7 + 1 = 2 + 3D  ⟹
>  2 + 3D ≥ 21  ⟹
>  D ≥ 6. That leaves D with 8 (other digits are taken).
>  ⟹ A + F + H + 1 = 25 ⟹ A = 25 - 9 - 7 - 1 = 7. And that is not possible.
>  [image: step4]

**Step 5**

> You can now see that 7, 8 and 9 can only be given to A, D and F.
>  [image: step5]

**Step 6**

> Let's substitute `F = C + H` in `A + F + H + 1 = C + DI`. ⟹
>  A + (C+H) + H + 1 = C + DI ⟹
>  A + 2H + 1 = DI ⟹
>  (7/8/9) + 2(4/5) + 1 = (2/3) * (7/8/9) ⟹
>  (16..20) = (2/3) * (7/8/9)  ⟹
>  (16..20) = 2 * (8/9). So I = 2 and D = 8 or 9.
>
>  Lets try them both:
>  **D = 8**:
>  (7/9) + 2(4/5) + 1 = 16 ⟹ 7 + 2 * 4 + 1 = 16
>  gives: A = 7, H = 4, I = 2, D = 8.
>  This means F = 9, C = 5 (F=C+H), B = 3 (H>B)
>  **but:** `E ≠ H + I` ⟹ 6 ≠ 4 + 2, so this solution is not correct!
>
>  **D = 9**:
>  (7/8) + 2(4/5) + 1 = 18 ⟹ 7 + 2 * 5 + 1 = 18
>  gives: A = 7, H = 5, I = 2, D = 9. This means F = 8, C = 3 (F=C+H).
>  And that leaves B = 4
>  [image: step6]

**Let's check our work:**

> CG = C ⟹ 5 * 1 = 5
>  6C = CE ⟹ 6 * 5 = 5 * 6
>  B + 3 ≠ 2A ⟹ 4 + 3 ≠ 2 * 7
>  3I ≥ B ⟹ 3 * 2 ≥ 4
>  F ≠ A + D ⟹ 8 ≠ 7 + 9
>  F = C + H ⟹ 8 = 3 + 5
>  3I ≤ 9 ⟹ 3 * 2 ≤ 9
>  C + E ≥ A ⟹ 3 + 6 ≥ 7
>  A + F + H + 1 = C + DI ⟹ 7 + 8 + 5 + 1 = 3 + 9 * 2
>  E ≠ H + I ⟹ 6 ≠ 5 + 2
>  H > B ⟹ 5 > 4